# RTC query to get each day effort

Tags: rational-team-concert

How to query in RTC 7.0.2 for a formal project, to get each day effort (time tracking) or time spent each day for a task?

Answer (score 0):

That might have changed since 2015, but [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/155474/set-by-java-api-time-tracking) mentioned

> Time tracking is not a field/an attribute. Time tracking entries are added to a work item using a reference/link. I know that others have done this in the past.

The article which deals with this topic is "[The Work Item Time Tracking API](https://rsjazz.wordpress.com/2015/03/31/the-work-item-time-tracking-api/)" from [Ralph](http://en.gravatar.com/rsjazz)

The following code update or create time tracking entries, but, in the process, access and read existing time tracking first, which is of interest here.

```java
public void updateOrCreateTimeSheetEntry(WorkItemWorkingCopy workingCopy,
        ITimeCode timeCode, Timestamp startDateTimeStamp,
        Duration workDuration, Identifier workType,
        IProgressMonitor monitor) throws TeamRepositoryException {

    // set the active work item from the working copy
    setWorkItem(workingCopy.getWorkItem());

    // Find a matching time sheet if it exists.
    ITimeSheetEntry timeSheet = findTimeSheetEntry(timeCode,
            startDateTimeStamp, monitor);
    if (timeSheet == null) {
        // There is no time sheet for this entry
        // Create a new one and create the link
        timeSheet = createTimeSheet();
        workingCopy.getReferences()
                .add(WorkItemEndPoints.WORK_TIME,
                        IReferenceFactory.INSTANCE
                                .createReferenceToItem(timeSheet));
        // Add the entry to the map to hold the data
        addEntry(timeSheet, monitor);
    } else {
        // There is a time sheet, we need to update it
        // Get the workingCopy of the time sheet
        timeSheet = (ITimeSheetEntry) timeSheet.getWorkingCopy();
        // remove the time spent from current time
        setTotalDuration(new Duration(getTotalDuration().longValue()
                - timeSheet.getTimeSpent().longValue()));
    }

    // Set the new data
    timeSheet.setStartDate(startDateTimeStamp);
    timeSheet.setTimeCodeId(timeCode.getTimeCodeId());
    // TODO: If I leave this out it fails....
    timeSheet.setTimeCode(timeCode.getTimeCodeLabel());
    timeSheet.setTimeSpent(workDuration);
    timeSheet.setWorkType(workType);
    // add the new time back
    setTotalDuration(getTotalDuration().add(workDuration));
    // Update the value
    // Note: it is important to set the duration value, of the work item
    // otherwise the work item is not marked as dirty and in need to update
    // in the repository and the save process will not save the time sheet
    getWorkItem().setDuration(getTotalDuration().longValue());
    workingCopy.getDependentItems().add(timeSheet);
}
```

You can [make a query to fetch work items for a given date](https://jazz.net/library/article/1007), used [a stored query](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/ResourceOrientedWorkItemAPIv2#Using_Stored_Queries), and list your work items that way.